# ¿Es posible parar la ejecución de un cógido en Python hasta que finalice una ejecución en segundo plano lanzada por ese mismo script?

Tags: python

Tengo un script de Python para procesar imágenes que consiste en aplicar diferentes funciones a una imagen. Para ello, se definen varias funciones que ejecutan comandos externos mediante `subprocess.run()` (he probado también con `subprocess.call()` y `os.system()` pero tampoco funciona). De acuerdo con la documentación disponible, este comando debería a esperar a que acabara la `funcion1` para ejecutar la `funcion2` (esto en pricnipio no debería suponer problemas. Sin embargo, en este caso, el input de la `funcion2` es la imagen obtenida por la `funcion1`). El problema surge cuando, al tratarse de procesamientos pesados y costosos en tiempo, se ejecuta la `funcion2` antes de haber finalizado la `funcion1`.

Por ello, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de poder hacer que el código no se siga ejecutando hasta que las ejecuciones en segundo plano acaben. He probado con `time.sleep()` y `Event().wait()` pero no me sirve ya que paran también las acciones que se están ejecutando en segundo plano.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

*Pongo un ejemplo del fragmento de código:*

```
import subprocess 

def funcion1(directorio, args):    
    cmd = directorio + args
    subprocess.run(cmd)
def funcion2(directorio, args):    
    cmd = directorio + args
    subprocess.run(cmd)
 
funcion1(directorio1, args1) #directorio1: donde se encuentra la imagen original
funcion2(directorio2, args2) #directorio2: donde se encuentra la imagen obtenida mediante funcion1
```

Comment: El `run()` no es asincrónico, es decir, `funcion1()` no termina hasta que corra completamente el comando. Otro tema es si el `cmd` que ejecuta dispara un proceso en segundo plano, pero sin saber exactamente que es `cmd` imposible decirte nada. Por otro lado ¿qué es `directorio + args`? ¿es realmente un comando a ejecutar?

Answer (score 0):

Quizá esto te pueda servir:

Se me ocurre que puedes introducir un bucle que se repita cada poco tiempo y compruebe la fecha de modificación del archivo que resulta de la función 1, y la compare con la fecha de creación, o directamente compruebes si el archivo existe (Desconozco como funciona tu script exactamente, pero algo así te debería servir)

Para comprobar la fecha de modificación puedes usar esto:

```
import os
import datetime
def modification_date(filename):
    t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
```

Espero que te ayude o te de alguna idea. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! He intentado hacerlo de las dos maneras que propones, pero aunque me haga las comprobaciones, no consigo el resultado que quiero. El problema es que, si quiero que el bucle se repita cada 'x' tiempo, las actividades que se están ejecutando en segundo plano dejan de realizarse (he probado con el módulo `schedule` pero obtengo los mismos resultados que con `time.sleep` y `event().wait()`).

Comment: ¿Y has probado con el módulo queue? Parece que es lo que andas buscando... https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue